# Silverlight Windows Pone: Compiler Error when adding handler for custom event from inside listbox datatemplate

Tags: windows, silverlight-3.0, windows-phone-7

I have scratched my head at this for a long time - and i probably am missing something thats right in my face.

I am creating a listbox with a usercontrol as its item. I have defined an event that fires from my user control and i want to handle that in the page that hosts the listbox.

**Event Defintion in the usercontrol**

```
 public delegate void TaskListItemMultiSelectViewEventHandler(TaskDataModel currentTask);
    public event TaskListItemMultiSelectViewEventHandler TaskListItemMultiSelectViewEvent;
```

Event Handler in the page.xaml that hosts the listbox

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">
    <ListBox x:Name="TaskListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" MouseLeftButtonUp="TaskListBox_MouseLeftButtonUp">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <mycontrol:TaskListItemControl TaskListItemMultiSelectViewEvent="TaskListItemControl_TaskListItemMultiSelectViewEvent"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

And in the page's code behind,

```
 private void TaskListItemMultiSelectViewEvent_TaskListControl(TaskDataModel currentTask)
    {
        if (TaskListMultiSelectViewEvent != null)
            TaskListMultiSelectViewEvent(currentTask);
    }
```

**Problem:**

When i compile this, i get a compile error 
***Error 12 No overload for 'TaskListItemMultiSelectViewEvent_TaskListControl' matches delegate 'TaskListItemMultiSelectViewEventHandler***

Any help to suggest what might be wrong is appreciated. I have been staring at this for too long!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had the event signature cannot be just anything but has to be EventHandler(object sender, some_EventArgs_type e)